# What is 1 dimensional string array?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, c-strings

1- What is 1 dimensional string array?

2- Is `char *[]` 2 dimensional ?

3- Is `char *[]` 1 dimensional string array?

Thanks.

Comment: They would be 1-dimensional arrays of pointer-to-char if the definitions were complete for example: `char *array[] = {"one", "two"};` or `char *array[2];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char *[]` is an incomplete type of one-dimensional array of pointers to the type char.

You could write for example

```
char *s[] = { "string1", "string2", "string3" };
```

and in this case the array s is an array of three pointers to string literals.

If you will declare an array outside any function like

```
char *s[];
```

then you will get a tentative definition of a one-dimensional array with one element.

A declaration of a two-dimensional array looks like

```
char s[N1][N2];
```

or

```
char s[][N2] = { /* some initializers */ };
```

where `N1` and `N2` are some positive integers.

Whether a one-dimensional or a two-dimensional character array contains string(s) depends on the user of the array.

Here is an example

```
char s1[] = "Hello";
char s2[6] = "Hello";
char s3[5] = "Hello";
```

Here the arrays s1 and s2 contain a string while the array s3 does not contain a string because it does not include the terminating zero of the string literal used as an initializer.

Or

```
char * s[] = { "Hello" };
```

This array does not contain a string. It is an array of one pointer to a string literal.

Comment: Thanks. I understood